# How do i make the first payment made for each pledge, display “first payment” on that output row

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE 
    pledgeid dd_pledge.idpledge%TYPE;
    amtpledge dd_pledge.pledgeamt%TYPE;
    monthspay dd_pledge.paymonths%TYPE;
    datepay dd_payment.paydate%TYPE;
    amtpay dd_payment.payamt%TYPE;
    donorid dd_pledge.iddonor%TYPE;
    CURSOR cur_pledges IS
    SELECT pl.idpledge, pl.pledgeamt, pl.paymonths, pay.paydate, pay.payamt, pl.iddonor 
    FROM dd_pledge pl JOIN dd_payment pay 
    ON pl.idpledge = pay.idpledge 
    WHERE pl.iddonor = 309
    ORDER BY pl.idpledge, pay.paydate;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_pledges;
    LOOP 
        FETCH cur_pledges INTO pledgeid, amtpledge, monthspay, datepay, amtpay, donorid;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pledge ID: '|| pledgeid  || ' Pledge Amount: '|| amtpledge || ' Monthly Payments:  '|| monthspay || ' Payment Date: '|| datepay || ' Amount Paid: '|| amtpay );
    EXIT WHEN cur_pledges%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_pledges;
END;
```

Please help!!! I am not able to figure out how to just provide a message for the first payment

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then put the `dbms_output` message before the `open`.

Comment: thank you, but that does not work. My code works... i am getting an output but for every first payment of the same pledge id i need to display a message that says "first payment"